# How to check the amount of memory a single/set of lines in python is using?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I added several lines to a python codebase and now the memory is exceeding the limits. Is there a way to see how much memory a particular line or set of lines is using in Python?

Here's the set of lines that I added

```
    df["value_weighted_average"] = (
      df.reset_index().merge(df2merge, on='vid', suffixes=['','_x'])
      .assign(proportions=lambda x: (x[['first','first_x']].min(axis=1) - x[['second','second_x']].max(axis=1)))
      .query('proportions >= 0')
      .groupby('index')['proportions'].sum()
    )
```

`df1.shape` is ttypically about `O(10^5) x O(10^1)`.
`df2.shape` is typically about `O(10^7) x O(10^1)`.

I'm not well versed with Python, but I think the `merge` operation is what's introducing a lot of memory usage

Comment: Objects, not lines of code, consume memory. So it would depend on the lines you added and what objects you created in those lines. Post the code you added and it *may* be enough to help answer your question. The more detail the better.

Comment: @Woodford Just put in the OP the lines that I added

Comment: Try looking at [Monitoring memory usage of a running Python program](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/monitoring-memory-usage-of-a-running-python-program/amp/).